# Prove $[0,1]$ isn't a differential variety or manifold.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

> Prove $[0,1]$ isn't a differential variety or manifold with the usual topology in $[0,1]$.

Well my idea is using the definition of differential structure we can see that $[0,1]$ doesn't have a differential structure so it can't be a manifold.

In my opinion the point that make that $[0,1]$ isn't a manifold is that if we take charts like $(a,b)$ with $0 < a < b < 1$ or $[0,a)$ or $(a,1]$ and a the identity as the function of the charts $(U_i,Id)$ $\forall i \in I$ it provoques that the image of $[0,a)$ or $(a,1]$ isn't an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology.

I don't know if I am in a correct way or not.

Comment: You're on the right track, but one issue with your start is that you're focusing on individual charts, when you need to prove a universal negative. Hint: focus on the endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differentiable structure is not necessary here. The point is that the unit interval $[0,1]$ with its usual topology is not locally homeomorphic to an open interval.

To prove this, you must prove that *no* charts exists at the boundary points, but you had the idea right. A *connected* open neighborhood in $[0,1]$ of either boundary point is homeomorphic to a half-open half-closed interval. Since you can always find a connected subneighborhood, we can restrict to this case. Hence if we prove a half-open half-closed interval is not homeomorphic to an open interval, we will be done.

This can be done with a connectedness argument: removing any point from an open interval will disconnect it, but removing the present boundary point from a half-open half-closed interval leaves it connected. Hence these spaces cannot be homeomorphic.

It's worth remarking that if you really want to prove the usual topology on the unit interval is not a topological manifold, you must check this for arbitrary open subsets of Euclidean space and not just open intervals. It's a significant theorem that Euclidean spaces of different dimension are not homeomorphic.

You can still use connectedness arguments to differentiate between half-open half-closed intervals and opens subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ for $n\geq 2$ however: removing *two* points disconnects the former but not the latter.

Comment: So if I take as open set U = $[0,1]$ and the Identity as the function and I prove that Id: U --> U $\subset \mathbb{R^2}$ carry open set to a non open set that implies that Id isn't a homeomorphism it will be finish the problem no?

Comment: @Maths4Life no! You are proving that a *particular candidate for a chart* is not a chart, but that's not enough. You must prove *there does not exist a chart*.

Comment: And how can I prove that there does not exist a chart?

Comment: I tried to explain this in my answer: if we take a sufficiently small neighborhood of an endpoint, then a chart would be a homeomorphism of a half-open half-closed interval with an open subset of Euclidean space. But no such homeomorphism exists.

Comment: I don't understand the mean of "sufficiently small neighborhood of an endpoint"

Comment: There are all kinds of open neighborhoods of the endpoint $0\in [0,1]$. For instance, you can look at $[0,\frac 1{100})\cup (\frac 2{100},\frac 3{100})$. But as you see, you can always find a smaller neighborhood which is connected, like $[0,\frac 1{100})$. Now, because it's possible to do this, I *assume* we're dealing with such a neighborhood.

Comment: Okay, I understand it.